# Can actions dispatched using mapDispatchToProps be accessed in any component or just in the component mapDispatchToProps is written

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When we write `mapDispatchToProps` in any component , I know we can call/dispatch the action using `this.props.action()` in the same component  - but my query is if I need to call/dispatch the same action/s(for which I have written mapDispatchToProps in some component) in some other component do I need to write `mapDispatchToProps` again or is there any way like I can write mapDispatchToProps just once and then use this.props.action() in any component

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to do both i.e., connect components directly to store or receive props explicitly from parent components.

- **Connecting components directly to store**

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { email } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{email}</p>
                <Baz />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  ({
    email: state.email
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```

```
class Baz extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { action } = this.props;

        return (
            <button onClick={action}>Call me!</button>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    action
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);
```

- **Receive props from parent**

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { action, email } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{email}</p>
                <Baz action={action} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  ({
    email: state.email
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    action
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);

class Baz extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { action } = this.props;

        return (
            <button onClick={action}>Call me!</button>
        )
    }
}

export default Baz;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass the action down to child component with props, otherwise I believe  you'll have to mapDispatchToProps in each component

Answer (score 0):

If your the same components controlled by a parent component, you can create an container to wrap some child Component. Container will connect to redux and defined functions dispatch, get state from store and then, pass them into child Components like this:

```
Class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child1 state1={this.props.state1} action1={this.props.action1} />
                <Child2 state1={this.props.state2} action1={this.props.action2} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   state1: state.state1,
   state2: state.state2,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   action1: dispatch({type: ..., payload: ...}),
   action2: dispatch({type: ..., payload: ...})
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container)
```

**Otherwise, I recommend you should defined mapDispatchToProps in each component**